# Can Azure AD federate to a 3rd-party IdP without a persistent sync to that IdP?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identity, federation

The 3rd-party IdP (not a Microsoft product) already exists and manages hundreds or thousands of users in multiple domains.  That IdP must remain authoritative for those users.  I don't want Azure AD (AAD) to get cluttered up by getting a copy of all the info for all of those users.  I don't want there to be any chance that AAD has a copy and then somehow AAD's view of some user gets out-of-sync with the 3rd-party IdP's view.  I just want AAD to ask (federate) the IdP for the info and authentication whenever an app needs to authenticate or authorize a user (that AAD doesn't know about -- AAD *will* know about *some* users for some apps).  The app will not know about the 3rd-party IdP.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is simply called Direct Federation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation